# raspberry pi does not have /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, spi

I bought an PiFace and I want to follow [this](http://www.startpi.co.uk/getting-started-with-pi-face.html) guide, but I don't have the `raspi-blacklist.conf`.

There were my steps so far:

1. I've installed my rpi by following [this](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianInstaller) guide.
2. I've executed `sudo rpi-update`
3. I tried to find `raspi-blacklist.conf`

Does anybody have some insights for me?

Answer (score 9):

I think Rasbian removed the whole default raspi-blacklist.conf file sometime ago. Instead of editing the */boot/config.txt* as suggested by Stabby.

The better way of doing it without going to change the file is use raspi-config to change the setting for you.

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Then select

```
advance options
```

Select

```
A6 SPI  Enable/Disable automatic loading
```

and say yes to all the options.

You can also enable i2c here. reboot the system and you should see *spidev0.0* and *spidev0.1* in *dev*

Comment: As of Raspbian Jessie (Nov 2016) options to turn SPI on/off can be found via  `sudo raspi-config`  `5 Interfacing Options`  `P4 SPI Enable/Disable automatic loading of SPI kernel module (needed for e.g. PiFace)`

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old thread, but it bothered me that it didn't have an answer.
My raspbian wheezy also doesn't have raspi-blacklist.conf, and creating commented out one doesn't make any sense.

What worked for me was editing */boot/config.txt* and adding line:

```
dtparam=spi=on
```

After reboot /dev/spidev0.0 was there

Answer (score 2):

This is a blacklist file, and is used to prevent the kernel from loading unecessary modules. In any case, if you're using raspbian wheezy, the default file is

```
# blacklist spi and i2c by default (many users don't need them)

blacklist spi-bcm2708
blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

Try that. Otherwise, let us know what distro you are using, if not wheezy.

To create the file:
Wheezy comes stocked with nano, so let's use that as our editor. The directory should exist, as it contains some also modeule config files. Try:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
```

You are now editing the file you wish to create. Enter the lines above that I indicated. When finished, type ctrl-x, then answer yes and hit return. The file is now created. You need to set permissions on the file by:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf
```

Your file should now be there and ready to go. You should now be able to edit it as in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know what the file is for, but my problem is that I don't have the file.

Comment: @HansElsen If it doesn't exist you can created it. In UNIX-like systems *everything is a file*. I get you're on Raspbian?

Comment: I didn't figure you can just create the file to make it work. But not having this file, doesn't that mean that the interfaces in that file are not blacklisted at all?

Comment: Correct. You're going to comment out one of the two lines if you follow the tutorial.

Comment: I'm finding that this doesn't answer my question (the same as the OPs).   WHY doesn't the file exist in the first place?   There seems to be little point in creating the file then commenting out the contents!?   I'm using raspbian....